# How can I have type inference for the second generic parameter if I give the first one explicitly?

Tags: typescript

How can I have type inference for the second generic parameter if I give the first one explicitly?

```js
type Definition<T, U> = U & ThisType<T & U>;

function foo<T, U extends object = object>(
  name: string,
  definition: Definition<T, U>
) {}

foo<{ b: string }>("a", {
  a() {
    // can use declared properties in the first generic parameter
    this.b;
    
    // I got `Property 'c' does not exist on type '{ b: string; } & object'`
    // I hope I can use c() as well
    this.c();
    
    // 
    // @ts-expect-error
    this.notDefined;
  },
  c() {},
});
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdo4iD2yA8AVANFAKoB8UAvMVAGRS4AWiAzruBHjcSQNwBQv8AK7IAxuixR4GDHkJEoEAB7AIyACZMoGAEYArCGIpa9B4CQAUvKFGQBDALYQAXFCbAATigDm+K1DUIKGiYyC5wSKjiOARcvACUUADeAL78UjKJUNoubp7IXlDJFgBEtsWEiX625gmV1tYA9A1QIrbIUIJM0AEiADa27hBqUGDuGJDu6BCaKFDA9NBI7m5QXqoQniIjAw4QKu5+1vPMAHTafPVQh1BNUACSqxjAUAAGAApjE6BQAOQiP-4MNMbE8FIpmM8JKBIL9MtlXB5vNxCpwdPoxD8Xtdbg96ONoA9Wu1OtARDUoLZNAB3CC9XrXY5ME5kuIXerY5ocqAAAWATAAtEpIGJBe4xgdLoyTsgnuEUEM2clfNYWUklbxkqzeEA

Comment: Are you trying to call U's c() method from T using `this.c()`?

Comment: I expect T will be `{ b: string }` and U will be `{ c: () => void }` in this case, and `ThisType<T & U>` makes both `b` and `c` available

Comment: This is currently not possible; the most common workaround is currying as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEpykW).  See the linked questions and answers for more information.